# Script operating backwards

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to figure out why my script seems to be working in reverse. I have a page where there are hidden elements that will be shown when an image is clicked. The content should be hidden when the page is loaded, and only shown when the button is clicked. However, the page is loading with the content shown, and the images that are clicked actually hides the content,

The page is http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/is...ive-Nonfiction and there are headings on the lower right hand side with images next to them (circles with "+" signs in them) One of those are "Complexity Factors", and the grey sub headings under it is what should be hidden.

```
  <script> 
                                               $(document).ready(function() 
          { $('div.hiddenComplexity').hide();});
            $('div.expandingBtn').click(function() 
          {$('div.hiddenComplexity').slideToggle('fast'); 
            });  


    </script>
```

My jQuery script is:
where .hiddenComplexity is the div that has the content that should be hidden under "Complexity Factors", but it is showing instead, and hides when clicked (the opposite as intended). .expandingBtn is the name of the DIV that is clicked to show the hidden content. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Checked the console for errors? Looks like you may be missing a `})` in your code too.

Comment: Turns out I actually had too many :-\

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. It was my syntax :-\ I had too many of these }); in there. I had to refer to w3schools and check the syntax and when I structured it correctly, it works. (I edited the script in the original post)
Now to work out the issue of how to toggle the images between a "+" and a "-" (yes, he client demands that it is an image.)